# Extract N values from 2 dataframes (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i have 2 pandas dataframes with same columns [*id*, *value*].

I want to create a new dataframe extracting 200 *values* for each *id* taking instances from the first df1 and if it hasn't enough values i should go to the second df2 to take remaining *values*.

How can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate two dataframe and extract the values with `groupby().head()`.

```
(pd.concat((df1, df2))
  .groupby('id').head(200)
)
```